# Reportar progresso para interface de um método assíncrono em C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, thread, async

Tenho uma aplicação `Windows Forms`. Esta aplicação irá executar alguns processos que levam um certo tempo para executar, portanto, gostaria de executa-los de forma paralela. Segue um pouco do que estou tentando implementar.

No construtor do formulário, crio uma lista genérica (`ProcessViewModel`) de objetos chamada `Processes`, com algumas informações pertinentes a cada execução.

```
private List<ProcessViewModel> Processes { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Processes  = new List<ProcessViewModel>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       Processes.Add(new ProcessViewModel() 
                         {  
                            Id = i, 
                            Process = "Process " + i,
                            Status = "Stopped", 
                            Progress = 0,
                            Max = 3000
                         });
    }
}
```

Quando o usuário clicar em um botão, vou iniciar cerca de 10 processos através do método `ProcessObject`, que por sua vez irá realizar um processamento pesado (diversos cálculos estatísticos). Então eu percorro esta lista de processos e repasso como um argumento para um método assíncrono.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // esta lista contém 10 objetos que servem como parametros para cada processo
    foreach (var process in Processes)
        await ProcessObject(process);
}
```

No meu método assíncrono eu recebe o argumento e irei realizar esta operação que contém um loop e neste loop (meu processamento) e gostaria de notificar o progresso deste processamento para uma interface.

```
private async Task ProcessObject(ProcessViewModel process)
{
    process.Status = "Starting";
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
       process.Progress = 0;
       do
       {
            process.Status = "Running";

           // aqui entra meu processamento pesado

           // gostaria de atualizar meu objeto aqui
           process.Progress++;

           // feedback para interface
           UpdateRow(process);                

       } while (process.Progress < process.Max && /*outra condição estatística*/);

    });    
}
```

Como eu terei 10 processo operantes ao mesmo tempo, pensei em fazer uma grid, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o método que atualiza uma grid com as informações de progresso de cada atividade.

```
private void UpdateRow(ProcessViewModel process)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[process.Index - 1].Cells[1].Value = process.Progress;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Acontece que quando chega o momento de atualizar a interface, estou obtendo uma exceção do tipo `InvalidOperationException`.

> Existe algum meio de realizar um processamento pesado e mandar um
>   feedback de modo assincrono para uma UI, sem interromper o
>   processamento?

Sei que em .Net, existem diversos recursos para programação concorrente como `Threads`, `Parallels` e `async/await`, `Task`, mas não sei ao certo qual devo utilizar para que minha aplicação consiga escalar da melhor maneira. Não sei se o que estou fazendo é a melhor maneira.

Comment: O que é este `Process` e consequentemente o `process`? "quando chega o momento de atualizar a interface" é vago. Tente colocar mais informações que ajude entender o todo. O `async` me parece ser uma solução adequada, e realmente ele precisa ser usado com cuidado com UI.

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta, obrigado @bigown

Comment: Alguns links que podem lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972268/async-await-with-a-winforms-progressbar, http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/729674/Simple-Net-progress-bar-using-async-await, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20820/use-and-understanding-of-async-await-in-net-4-5, http://www.danderson.me/posts/async-and-await-ui-synchronization-with-c-5-net-4-5-and-winforms/

Comment: Alterei minha pergunta, veja se ficou mais claro o que estou tentando rs. Obrigado @bigown

Comment: Uma forma seria utilizando de `Delegates` para fazerem o update na tua UI. Tens algum conhecimento sobre `Delegates?`

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade, Sim, geralmente trabalho com `Action<>` e `Func<>`, mas existe um meio de implementar isto de forma assíncrona? Como poderia fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A exceção em questão ocorre porque o Windows Forms não permite que você altere os controles do seu Form enquanto estiver executando de uma thread que não é a thread da interface gráfica.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode optar por uma das seguintes opções:

### 1. [**Progress Reporting**, com uma implementação de **IProgress<T>**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), para .NET 4.5.

Essa interface basicamente permite que você avise quando que houve alguma mudança no seu método assíncrono, permitindo que seja executada qualquer alteração dentro da thread da interface gráfica.

No seu exemplo, teria que ser alterado o seu método assíncrono:

```
private async Task ProcessObject(ProcessViewModel process, IProgress<ProcessViewModel> progress)
{
    // início do método...

    // avisa a interface
    progress.Report(process);

    // resto do método...       
}
```

Quando o método **Report()** for executado, o objeto progress executará o evento **ProgressChanged**, onde você deve atualizar a interface gráfica:

```
var progress = new Progress<ProcessViewModel>();
progress.ProgressChanged += progress_ProgressChanged;

void progress_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProcessViewModel e)
{
    UpdateRow(e);
}
```

### 2. A classe [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), a partir do .NET 2.0

Através dos métodos **Post()** e **Send()**, você consegue executar porções de código no contexto de uma thread diferente da que está executando a thread atual.

Dessa forma, você conseguiria fazer as suas chamadas aos controles dentro do seu próprio método assíncrono. Um exemplo:

```
public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
}

private SynchronizationContext m_SynchronizationContext;
```

E dentro do seu método assíncrono:

```
private async Task ProcessObject(ProcessViewModel process)
{
    // início do método...

    // atualiza a interface
    m_SynchronizationContext.Post((@object) => 
    {
        UpdateRow(@object);
    }, process);

    // resto do método...       
}
```

---

> Sei que em .Net, existem diversos recursos para programação concorrente como Threads, Parallels e async/await, Task, mas não sei ao certo qual devo utilizar para que minha aplicação consiga escalar da melhor maneira. Não sei se o que estou fazendo é a melhor maneira.

Nesse caso, tudo depende de qual será o fluxo de execução das suas threads.

Pelo seu exemplo, o async/await do clique do botão permitirá que o Form continue com a thread livre para interação enquanto os seus processamentos ocorrem, porém o await dentro do foreach indica que o programa deve esperar o fim do processamento para avançar na iteração do loop. Assim, os processamentos ocorrerão sequencialmente.

Caso os processos sejam independentes e possam ser executados em paralelo, tente utilizar um pouco do que a Task Parallel Library oferece:

```
var listTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var process in Processes)
{
    listTasks.Add(ProcessObject(process, progress));
}

await Task.WhenAll(listTasks.ToArray());
```

Dessa forma, o programa vai atribuir uma thread para cada execução do método ProcessObject() e o método **Task.WhenAll()** forçará esperar todos os processamentos finalizarem.